# Problem converting decimal to binary in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, binary, decimal

The following code is to convert decimal to binary.

My question is: When num becomes less than or equal to 1, python jumps to the last line i.e print(num % 2, end = '') and consequently prints out 1. But after that, why does it move to line 'decimalToBinary(num // 2)'? That line is supposed to execute only when num > 1

```
def decimalToBinary(num):
    if num > 1:
        decimalToBinary(num // 2)
    print(num % 2, end='')

decimalToBinary(17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the last function in the stack finished,so it jumps to the call point of the function in the upper stack.If you add `a=1` behind the `print(num%2,end='')` statement, you will see that `a=1` gets called before the control returns to the upper function.

Answer (score -3):

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

# Read the input
s = int(input())

# Write your code below

print(format(s, 'b'))
```